# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException on using Aspect

Tags: spring, spring-aop, aspect

**Spring boot version used:** 1.2.3

We are creating CacheManager based on a property like :

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() throws IOException {
    String cacheImpl = env.getProperty(CacheSupport.CACHE_PROPERTY, String.class, "");
    if (CacheSupport.AEROSPIKE.equalsIgnoreCase(cacheImpl)) {
        return aerospikeCacheManager();
    } else if (CacheSupport.REDIS.equalsIgnoreCase(cacheImpl)) {
        return redisCacheManager();
    } else {
        return guavaCacheManager();
    }
}
```

We have an AerospikeController like below :

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = CacheSupport.CACHE_PROPERTY, havingValue = CacheSupport.AEROSPIKE)
@Controller
public class AerospikeController {
  @Autowired
    private AerospikeCacheManager aerospikeCacheManager;
}
```

Things were working fine. Problem arises when i added below code for intercepting response times of aerospike calls:

```
@Component
```

@Aspect
public class WebServiceResponseTimeLogger {

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServiceResponseTimeLogger.class);

@Autowired
private AerospikeCacheManager cacheManager;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    LOG.info("WebServiceRequestTimeLogger initialized");
}

public WebServiceResponseTimeLogger() {
    super();
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.snapdeal.pie.web.aerospike.config.AerospikeCacheManager.*(..))")
public void pointcuts() {
}

@Around("pointcuts()")
public void logExternalCalls(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    long timeStartInMillisecs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pjp.proceed();
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    LOG.info("Time Taken to execute : {} {} is {} ms", new Object[] { signature, pjp.getArgs()[0], (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStartInMillisecs) });
}
```

}

I am getting below exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.snapdeal.pie.web.aerospike.config.AerospikeCacheManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Add @Qualifier(value = "cacheManager") to your autowired CacheManager in your AeospikeController or rename the variable name to cacheManager

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it says :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.snapdeal.pie.web.aerospike.config.AerospikeCacheManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Check if bean AerospikeCacheManager is created in this code correctly.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() throws IOException {
    String cacheImpl = env.getProperty(CacheSupport.CACHE_PROPERTY, String.class, "");
    if (CacheSupport.AEROSPIKE.equalsIgnoreCase(cacheImpl)) {
        return aerospikeCacheManager();
```

Comment: Yes the bean was created successfully. When i removed the aspect code , things are working fine.